# Why is my .pythonrc file being run in non-interactive programs?

Tags: python, macos, ipython, homebrew

Context: I started using OSX about a year ago, and I had a kind of screwy python installation. That is, I was using system python, and installed packages with sudo when that seemed to make things work. Now, I'm starting from a fresh OSX install, and trying to do it the Right Way. I've installed python and python3 from brew, and trying to use python3 whenever possible.

Problem: I have a .pythonrc file, which just imports a handful of commonly used packages - mostly standard lib, a few popular nonstandard packages, and a few of my own. In the past, this file has only been run when I start an interactive shell. Now, when using brew python, it is run whenever I run any python program.

There must be some gap in my understanding of the rc file - I thought the purpose was specifically for interactive use. Still, when I use system python, the rc file isn't used - so something is different about my system python (2.7.10 at /usr/bin/python) vs brew python (2.7.12 at /usr/local/bin/python; 3.5.2 at /usr/local/bin/python3). The behavior is the same if I remove everything except a print statement from the rc file.

edit: I realized that the rc file is running because I'm importing ipdb. This makes sense I suppose, but I still don't understand why that would happen in some of the python environments/versions but not others.

edit: [https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/blob/master/ipdb/**main**.py#L44](https://github.com/gotcha/ipdb/blob/master/ipdb/__main__.py#L44) this line fails, not sure if this means anything.

Full stacktrace from within .pythonrc:

```
  File "hello.py", line 1, in <module>
    from ipdb import set_trace
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipdb/__init__.py", line 7, in <module>
    from ipdb.__main__ import set_trace, post_mortem, pm, run             # noqa
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ipdb/__main__.py", line 51, in <module>
    ipapp.initialize([])
  File "<decorator-gen-109>", line 2, in initialize
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/traitlets/config/application.py", line 74, in catch_config_error
    return method(app, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/terminal/ipapp.py", line 315, in initialize
    self.init_code()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/shellapp.py", line 263, in init_code
    self._run_startup_files()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/shellapp.py", line 342, in _run_startup_files
    self._exec_file(python_startup)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/shellapp.py", line 328, in _exec_file
    raise_exceptions=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py", line 2469, in safe_execfile
    self.compile if kw['shell_futures'] else None)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.py", line 288, in execfile
    builtin_mod.execfile(filename, *where)
  File "~/.pythonrc", line 57, in <module>
    import traceback; traceback.print_stack()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can ask the traceback module:

```
$ cat .pythonrc
import traceback; traceback.print_stack()

$ cat test.py
import ipdb
```

Then by running

```
$ PYTHONSTARTUP="$HOME/.pythonrc" python test.py
```

you should get a traceback that tells you exactly from where the startup script is being run. Most likely, this is due to a call

```
start_ipython()
```

somewhere in the ipdb import.

Comment: I see an `ipapp.initialize([])`, no `start_ipython`. the `initialize` call is happening inside an `except` that happens after `get_ipython` fails. This seems informative, but I'm not quite sure what it means...

Comment: That just means that IPython has not been loaded yet. Can you post the full stack trace?

Comment: Stack trace added above.

Comment: Looking at the backtrace, ipdb should have something along the lines of `
    ipapp.exec_PYTHONSTARTUP = False` before calling ipapp.initialize([]). I would suggest filing a bug with the ipdb maintainers.